# jQuery.HighchartTable custom tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts, tooltip

I have to use jQuery HighchartTable for a project and need to customize the tooltips but I haven't found any options in documentation or here. Any ideas where to look? Thanks.

I tried this:

```
$('table.highchart').highchartTable({
    tooltip: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});
```

Comment: check http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.backgroundColor

Comment: yes I tried that also but without success

Comment: add fiddle sample where you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I read here: http://highcharttable.org/#doc-javascript, to change Highcharts options you need to do it in a special `beforeRender` event. So, for example, if you want to change tooltip's `backgroundColor`, you can use this code:

```
$('table.highchart')
  .bind('highchartTable.beforeRender', function(event, highChartConfig) {
    highChartConfig.tooltip = {
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    };
  })
  .highchartTable();
```

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.backgroundColor

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5L0wsndh/